# TextView text inconsistency

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, textview

So I've created a OnPageChangeListener and appended it to a ViewPager, all this done on the MainActivity class.

I've also done

```
@Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.d("ll",String.valueOf(position));
            TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPagina);
            t.setText("Page " + String.valueOf(position));
        }
```

So I can change the page's top text to display which page I'm currently in. However, this method is showing some very strange patterns:

1 - I start on "Page 0" (default text)

2 - Slide to the second page, change the name to "Page 1" **[WORKS]**

3 - ALL the remaining pages foward, no matter how many, will always have "Page 0" on it's text

4 - When I reach the last page and slide backwards (second last page), it will work; "Page ViewCount-1" - if I have 4 pages, it will show "Page 3" **[WORKS]**

*Observations:*

- I'm 100% sure I'm getting the correct values, since I'm getting the correct values on the Logcat window
- I'm creating this Listener inside the `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {` function

Comment: This could be due to multiple fragments having the same ID causing an issue in which one to update.  Does the text view only exist once?  Are you able to post the XML layouts? You state the default text is "Page 0" so this would possibly explain it.

Comment: Sure.

The TextView exists in the main fragment (file called fragment_main.xml) and it shows in all the pages.

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager); `

Comment: The TextView is defined in the fragment_main.xml and it's declared as follows:

` TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Page 0"
        android:id="@+id/txtPagina"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"/> `

Comment: The method I've implemented works fine from *Page 0* to *Page 1*, and from the last page to the second last page (let's say from *Page 9 last* to *Page 8*). If you want the actual .xml files I can upload them.

Comment: for a quick test, instead of assigning a text value, hide the view and see if there is still a view being displayed.  t.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

Comment: This is due to same ids of textview. You can find your fragment first, after that you will get the correct textview. View v = your current fragment . Then use    TextView t=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtPagina);

Comment: I need to understand what's happening. Why is it showing from first to second and from last to second last, but not on the other pages? And how do I get the current fragment?